# CSS Sticky footer with 100% width

Tags: css, width, footer, sticky

I'm trying to implement a sticky footer having a 100% of width. It should be stick on the bottom of the page, but not overlapping the page content div.
I'm using the page layout identical to this example:
http://peterned.home.xs4all.nl/examples/csslayout1.html

As you can see, the footer has the same width of div#container.
But I want to stretch the footer up to 100% width, whilst the page content stays centered and keeps stretching in height when resizing the browser.
How can I do that?

Comment: if you want to stretch the footer beyond the container, it needs to be out of the container, or to the width of the body. As for overlapping, use a low z-index on the footer and have the rest of the content with a higher z-index to have it overlap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## try this

*click le link to see new result*
http://jsfiddle.net/n6u3e/

```
/**
 * 100% height layout with header and footer
 * ----------------------------------------------
 * Feel free to copy/use/change/improve
 */

html,body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height:100%; /* needed for container min-height */
    background:gray;
    
    font-family:arial,sans-serif;
    font-size:small;
    color:#666;
}

h1 { 
    font:1.5em georgia,serif; 
    margin:0.5em 0;
}

h2 {
    font:1.25em georgia,serif; 
    margin:0 0 0.5em;
}
    h1, h2, a {
        color:orange;
    }

p { 
    line-height:1.5; 
    margin:0 0 1em;
}

div#container {
    position:relative; /* needed for footer positioning*/
    margin:0 auto; /* center, not in IE5 */
    width:750px;
    background:#f0f0f0;
    
    height:auto !important; /* real browsers */
    height:100%; /* IE6: treaded as min-height*/

    min-height:100%; /* real browsers */
}

div#header {
    padding:1em;
    background:#ddd url("../csslayout.gif") 98% 10px no-repeat;
    border-bottom:6px double gray;
}
    div#header p {
        font-style:italic;
        font-size:1.1em;
        margin:0;
    }

div#content {
    padding:1em 1em 5em; /* bottom padding for footer */
}
    div#content p {
        text-align:justify;
        padding:0 1em;
    }

div#footer {
    background:#ddd;
    border-top:6px double gray;
}
    div#footer p {
        padding:1em;
        margin:0;
    }
#barco{
width:750px;
    margin:auto;
}
```